# How to compare references of ClassInstanceCreation object and object passed as argument in MethodInvocation in AST Parser Java

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to compare the reference of two objects in AST Parser. For example: I have ClassInstanceCreation node

```
SomeNumber num = new SomeNumber();
```

and then I have MethodInvocation node

```
passNumber(num);
```

I need to check whether the two object references are same or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by matching the KEY value. For ClassInstanceCreation node, first i got the parent node and then i got the key of the parent node as follows:

```
((VariableDeclarationFragment) node.getParent()).resolveBinding().getKey()
```

then i got the key value of the argument of the MethodInvocation node as follows:

```
((Name) node.arguments().get(0)).resolveBinding().getKey()
```

and finally matching both the keys.